# Why is xml Validation failing?

Tags: java, spring, validation, integration

I am working on a Spring Integration project.  I have an xml input file that has had a style sheet applied to it. then it goes through a validation based on an xml schema.  The validation is failing without telling me anything about why it is failing.  The following is the log output with debug turned all the way up across the board.  Any ideas how can I find out why it failing?

```
 15:19:27.674 DEBUG [main]     [org.springframework.integration.xml.selector.XmlValidatingMessageSelector] Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors
    15:19:27.674 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] preSend on     channel 'sils-errors-validation-exception-channel', message: [Payload String content=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>
    <hcit:MessageHeader xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">
    <hcit:MessageSender>
    <hcit:OrganizationName>HJIP</hcit:OrganizationName>
    <hcit:ApplicationName>SILS</hcit:ApplicationName>
    <hcit:ContactName>HJIP Support</hcit:ContactName>
    <hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>612-348-6662</hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>
    </hcit:MessageSender>
    <hcit:MessageSentDateTime>2014-10-15T10:27:28</hcit:MessageSentDateTime>
   <hcit:ApplicationMessageID>9840306</hcit:ApplicationMessageID>
   <hcit:MessageTypeText>MODARR</hcit:MessageTypeText>
   <hcit:CommentText/>
   </hcit:MessageHeader>
   <SILSReplyAddUpdate>
   <hcit:MessageStatusText xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">Error</hcit:MessageStatusText>
   <hcit:MessageText xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">Booking Document has MNCIS case but no SILS ID - Booking Document thrown away</hcit:MessageText>
   <ActionResult>
   <ActionTypeText>AddSubjectEntity</ActionTypeText>
   <CaseTrackingID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" hcit:referenceID="2014005849-001"/>
   <SubjectEntityID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" hcit:referenceID="201401400"/>
   </ActionResult>
   </SILSReplyAddUpdate>
   </SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>
   ][Headers=     {replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@94b64e, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@94b64e, origMsgMemento=2192484046341591040, history=sils-errors-xform-gateway,sils-errors-inbound-channel,silsOrigMsgHdrEnricher,sils-errors_orig_stored_channel,SILS-xslt-transform,sils-errors-transformed-channel,sils-errors-validation-filter,sils-errors-validation-exception-channel, id=3da2f46d-786d-f00a-533f-61e12828fe26, timestamp=1414441167674}]
   15:19:27.674 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler#0 received message: [Payload String content=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>
    <hcit:MessageHeader xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">
    <hcit:MessageSender>
    <hcit:OrganizationName>HJIP</hcit:OrganizationName>
    <hcit:ApplicationName>SILS</hcit:ApplicationName>
    <hcit:ContactName>HJIP Support</hcit:ContactName>
    <hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>612-348-6662</hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>
    </hcit:MessageSender>
    <hcit:MessageSentDateTime>2014-10-15T10:27:28</hcit:MessageSentDateTime>
    <hcit:ApplicationMessageID>9840306</hcit:ApplicationMessageID>
    <hcit:MessageTypeText>MODARR</hcit:MessageTypeText>
    <hcit:CommentText/>
    </hcit:MessageHeader>
    <SILSReplyAddUpdate>
    <hcit:MessageStatusText
xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">Error</hcit:MessageStatusText>
    <hcit:MessageText xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">Booking Document has MNCIS case but no SILS ID - Booking Document thrown away</hcit:MessageText>
    <ActionResult>
    <ActionTypeText>AddSubjectEntity</ActionTypeText> 
    <CaseTrackingID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" hcit:referenceID="2014005849-001"/>
    <SubjectEntityID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" hcit:referenceID="201401400"/>
    </ActionResult>
    </SILSReplyAddUpdate>
    </SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>
     ]
```

and the schema it is being compare to is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema  xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" 
            xmlns:hcs="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils"  
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            targetNamespace="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.4.0">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" schemaLocation="HCITCommon-v2-2.xsd">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Schema describing HJIP message header.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:import>

    <xs:simpleType name="SILSActionType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Enumerated list of action names specific to SILS application services.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="AddSubjectEntityRecords"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="AddSubjectEntity"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="AddCourtCaseNumber"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="UpdateSubjectType"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="UpdateSubjectPrimary"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="UpdateTrackingOffense"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="SubjectEntityID" nillable="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Criminal justice person identifier. Commonly known as SILS identifier.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="hcit:ID" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="hcit:referenceID"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="CaseTrackingID" nillable="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Identifier for SILS case.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="hcit:ID" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="hcit:referenceID"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SILSReplyAddUpdate">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Return SILS message indicating status of add request.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="hcit:MessageReplyType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="ActionResult" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="ActionTypeText" type="hcs:SILSActionType"/>
                                    <xs:element ref="hcs:CaseTrackingID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xs:element ref="hcs:SubjectEntityID" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Document schema for processing SILS reply messages from Hennepin County.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="hcit:MessageHeader"/>
                <xs:element ref="hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdate"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You can see the XML it is trying to validate in the log output.

And here is the common schema referenced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2006 rel. 3 U (http://www.altova.com) by Information Technology (mn hennepin county) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.2">
    <xs:complexType name="AuditInfoType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Describes who is responsible for transaction event.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:UserID" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:UserRoleText" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ActionTypeText" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CodedElementType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for code value and corresponding description.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:CodeText"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:CodeDescription" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LogEventType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for describing a processing event during course of message exchange.  Calling application and application name will be same for top level event.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MessageText" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The event message text. May contain CDATA.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ExceptionText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The exception trace if any is available</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="EventLocation" type="hcit:LocationType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:EventTimeMilliseconds"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:EventDateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:LogLevelText"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:EnvironmentCode"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ThreadName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ApplicationName">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Event source or service application system.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ParentApplicationName"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LocationType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for describing code location where some processing event is specified.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ClassName" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Logging event source class or component name</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MethodName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Logging event source component method name</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Logging event source code line number</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MessageHeaderType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for metadata commonly used to administer message processing and debugging.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:MessageSender"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:MessageSentDateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ApplicationMessageID" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:MessageTypeText" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:RequestReply" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="CommentText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Generalized text message.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MessagePartyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for identifying party participating in message exchange.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:OrganizationName"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ApplicationName"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ContactName"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ContactPhoneNumber"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ContactEmailID" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:UserID" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MessageReplyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for reply status message.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MessageStatusText" type="hcit:MessageStatusTextType"/>
            <xs:element name="MessageText" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RequestReplyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for technical request reply meta data.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ReplyToQueueManagerName"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:ReplyToQueueName"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:CorrelationID" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TraceLogType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:TraceRequestIndicator"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:LogMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="ActionTypeText" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Action being performed; Add, Update, Delete</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ApplicationMessageID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Application assigned unique message identifier.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ApplicationName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Proper name of user domain and/or service application system.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ParentApplicationName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Calling application name.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="CodeDescription" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="CodeText" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="ContactEmailID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Email address to respond with notice about processing status such as system receipt confirmation, or processing error encountered, etc.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ContactName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Person or group name responsible for responding to questions about message processing or  debugging.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ContactPhoneNumber" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Telephone number associated with ContactName party.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="CorrelationID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Queue manager assigned message identiifer.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MessageHeader" type="hcit:MessageHeaderType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Metadata that is commonly used to administer message processing.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MessageSender" type="hcit:MessagePartyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for describing who initiated a message.  </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MessageSentDateTime" type="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Application assigned date time when message is sent.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MessageTypeText" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Determines how message is to be processed either by message broker  e.g Pub/Sub, Datagram,  or by an application. e.g. CaseGet, etc.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="OrganizationName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Owner name of system application.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ReplyToQueueManagerName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Location where message management software resides, typically a server name.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ReplyToQueueName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Technical name of message queue.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RequestReply" type="hcit:RequestReplyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for describing request/reply message parameters.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TraceLog">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Component for requesting trace event logging details to be returned with message response.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="hcit:TraceRequestIndicator"/>
                <xs:element ref="hcit:LogMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Network or application identifier of individual that initiated message.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="UserRoleText" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>User's role</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="DateOptionalTimeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(-\d{2}:\d{2})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="DateYearType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Four digit calendar year</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="IndicatorCodeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Indicates a Yes or No condition.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="N"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="MessageStatusTextType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Enumerated message status text.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Success"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Warning"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Error"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Failure"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="String40Type">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Structure for any text string restricted to 40 characters or less.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="40" fixed="false"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute name="actionTypeText" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Specific action being performed; e.g. Add, Update, Delete  as defined by business rules.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="asOfDateTime" type="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Metadata indicating business data is current as of date time</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="codeSource" type="xs:anyURI">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Resource identifier for encoded data set.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="lastUpdateDateTime" type="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>System date and time of last data modification.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="referenceID" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>An identifier used to correlate a piece of data with another.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:element name="EnvironmentCode" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Application environment; D = development, T = test, U= user acceptance, P= production</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="LogLevelText" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The event logging level</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ThreadName" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The event source thread name</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="EventDateTime" type="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The event date time formated.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="EventTimeMilliseconds" type="xs:decimal">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Event time expressed in number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 12 AM</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="LogEvent" type="hcit:LogEventType"/>
    <xs:element name="AuditInfo" type="hcit:AuditInfoType"/>
    <xs:element name="LogMessage" type="hcit:LogMessageType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="LogMessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:LogEvent"/>
            <xs:element ref="hcit:AuditInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="TraceRequestIndicator" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Numeric identifier</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RequestResponse" type="hcit:MessageReplyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Base response to request message.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Are you sure the validator has access to the "HCITCommon-v2-2.xsd" schema imported by your xsd?

Comment: Yes that file exists in the same directory. and I have added its contents to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>` is not declaring it's namespace, try adding

```
<hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg xmlns:hcs="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils">
```

By the way, this xml validates using oxygen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg xmlns:hcs="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils file:///xxx">
    <hcit:MessageHeader xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">
        <hcit:MessageSender>
            <hcit:OrganizationName>HJIP</hcit:OrganizationName>
            <hcit:ApplicationName>SILS</hcit:ApplicationName>
            <hcit:ContactName>HJIP Support</hcit:ContactName>
            <hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>612-348-6662</hcit:ContactPhoneNumber>
        </hcit:MessageSender>
        <hcit:MessageSentDateTime>2014-10-15T10:27:28</hcit:MessageSentDateTime>
        <hcit:ApplicationMessageID>9840306</hcit:ApplicationMessageID>
        <hcit:MessageTypeText>MODARR</hcit:MessageTypeText>
        <hcit:CommentText/>
    </hcit:MessageHeader>
    <hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdate>
        <hcit:MessageStatusText xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common"
            >Error</hcit:MessageStatusText>
        <hcit:MessageText xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common">Booking Document has
            MNCIS case but no SILS ID - Booking Document thrown away</hcit:MessageText>
        <hcs:ActionResult>
            <hcs:ActionTypeText>AddSubjectEntity</hcs:ActionTypeText>
            <hcs:CaseTrackingID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common"
                hcit:referenceID="2014005849-001"/>
            <hcs:SubjectEntityID xmlns:hcit="http://www.co.hennepin.mn.us/Common"
                hcit:referenceID="201401400"/>
        </hcs:ActionResult>
    </hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdate>
</hcs:SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg>
```

If you compare it with the one you have, you can see that SILSReplyAddUpdate is missing its prefix, same as ActionResult and its children.

If you don't want to add prefixes, you can use a default namespace for your root element, like this:

```
<SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg xmlns="http://hennepinsheriff.org/schema/sils">
```

Comment: It is the first element.  SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg.  Scroll to the right on the code block.

Comment: Updated my answer, try adding the namespace to your root element

Comment: I can't change the xml directly.  It is pulled off a queue and then has a style sheet applied to it.  written by someone else.

Comment: I ended up modify the style sheet applied to add that namespace to the SILSReplyAddUpdateMsg tag.